# Можно ли использовать разные декораторы в зависимости от аргументов функции в python?

Tags: python, декоратор

Например, если функция получает на вход *args, использовать один декоратор, а в случае передачи именованных параметров а=1, с=2 - другой
Вот я тут использую один декоратор в обоих случаях, но теоретически можно ли определить какой декоратор исползовать?

```
def fdecorator2(func):
  
  def inner(*args, **kwargs):
    tup = args
    dic = kwargs
    res = func(*args, **kwargs)
    if tup == ():
      print('num_wrapper_positional is used: ',dic)
    else:
      print('num_wrapper_named is used: ',tup)
    return int(res)
  
  return inner

@fdecorator2
def test(a1=0, a2=0):
    return a1 + a2
```

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что это очень плохой код?)

Comment: Приведите пример, для чего вам это нужно, может быть, Вам предложат вариант получше

Comment: Напишите свой декоратор, который это будет диспетчить)

Comment: Вы же в курсе, что декоратор - это просто функция? Её можно вызывать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то вроде этого?

```
if tup == ():
  res = num_wrapper_positional(func)(*args, **kwargs);
else:
  res = num_wrapper_named(func)(*args, **kwargs);
```